# Django Queryset same template for different views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have two view functions in the view.py

```
def function1(request):
   qset = Table1.objects.values(
    'Field1__code',
    'Field2__descr',
    'Field3__nr',   
    ...
    )

return render(request, 'template.html', {'qset':qset})


def function2(request):
   qset = Table2.objects.values(
    'Field4__abc',
    'Field5__def',
    'Field6__fgh',  
    ...
    )

return render(request, 'template.html', {'qset':qset})
```

I want to use the same template.html for both views.
How can I send from both functions in the content {'qset':qset} to the template same key names, like "x1", "x2", "x3" (or qset.x1, qset.x2, qset.x3) instead of sending two different sets of keys? 
The template.html contains keys "x1", "x2", "x3".
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are three options that I can think of quickly.

First, you use `.values_list` and use positional indexing rather than keys. So in your question you ask for `qset.x1, ...`. You'd use `qset.0, qset.1` instead. However, this is difficult to maintain.

Second, you could annotate the queryset to define the fields:

```
Table2.objects.annotate(
    x1=F('Field4__abc'),
    x2=F('Field5__def'),
    ...
).values('x1', 'x2', ...)
```

Third, you could create a dummy view model to translate the Model instances into it.

```
class ViewModel:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

def function2(request):
    table2s = Table2.objects.all()
    data = [
        ViewModel(x1=obj.Field4.abc, x2=Field5.def, ...)
        for obj in table2s
    ]
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'data':data})
```

The number of fields and complexity of logic will determine which will suit you best.